# external and internal loadbalancer with traefik

Tags: consul, traefik, consul-template

I am trying to set up traefik with an internal load balancer (that can contact the apps) and an external loadbalancer (that all the ingress goes through but forwards all trafik to the internal trafik server). My services themselves are registered in consul.

The closest I get to a solution is to use consul-template to build a file based configuration for the external LB and a consul-catalog based config for the internal one.

I would like to have it so that the external LB is having a backend defined for the internal LB that comes from consulCatalog, but I manually (or consul-template based) create the frontend for each domain.

How could I achieve that? I am fairly new to traefik...